# What is a good library for generating static Treemap graphs, usable on a server?

Tags: c#, java, charts

I'm busy with an application that needs to display Treemaps to a user but I can't find a good charting library that has support for this kind of graph.

[Here are some examples of what I mean](http://flowingdata.com/2010/02/11/an-easy-way-to-make-a-treemap/)

I'm using C# as a server side technology, but I'm willing to invoke something on a command-line too if that is required.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I don't mind getting a java library recommendation, since I don't mind combining technologies

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you question is tagged with "Java" I'm gonna propose [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (even though your actual question seems  to indicate you need more of a C#/.net kind of library)

Comment: Are you certain JFreeChart supports Treemaps ?

Comment: Well no, it doesn't have a treemap specific thing, but you can easily roll your own starting from it's basic components.

Comment: Roll-your-own is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It's appropriate for component providers but not for business problem solvers.